# Best place to require modules which are only used in closures

Tags: node.js, memory

If, as part of a NodeJS file, there are different closures:

```
const Library2 = require('Library2'); // should it be here?

doSomething().then(()=>{
    const Library1 = require('Library1'); // or here?
    return Library1.doSomething();
}).then(()=>{
    return Library2.doSomething();
}).then(...) // etc.
```

Would it be better to `require` Library1 and Library2 in the scopes in which they are used? Or at the top of the file like most do?

Does it make a difference to how much memory is consumed either way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is best to load all modules needed at server startup time.

When a module is loaded for the first time, it is loaded with blocking, synchronous I/O.  It is bad to ever use blocking, synchronous I/O during the run-time for your server because that interferes with the ability of your server to handle multiple requests at once and reduces scalability.

Modules loaded with `require()` are cached so fortunately, trying to `require()` in a module in the middle of a request handler really only hurts performance the very first time the request is run.

But, it's still best to load any modules in your startup code and NOT during the run-time request-handling of your server.